# How to set previous bullet points to transparent in beamer?

Tags: list, beamer

I am trying to make a bullet point

\begin{itemize}[<+->]

\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\Item Item 3

\end{itemize}

where on the first slide we see only Item 1, on the second one we see Item 1 in transparent and Item 2 full and on the next one we see Item 1 and Item 2 transparent and Item 3 full. I know there are modes to do this in the other direction (to see future bullet points transparent) but I can't find out how to do it the way I want.

Comment: Please always include a [mre] in your questions!

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}[<+|visible@+->]
    \item Item 1 
    \item Item 2 
    \item Item 3
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Will the initial command \setbeamercovered{transparent} affect other bullet points in the presentation?

Comment: @P.C.Spaniel Yes, but you can use it locally in a group to make sure that it only affects a single frame.